# onListItemClick, what statement do I need to get the value?

Tags: android, android-listview

i can add to a db and list as a listview.
When I click a list item using onListItemClick, what statement do I
need to get the value?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
private static String[] FROM = { _ID, DESCRIPTION, UN };
private static String ORDER_BY = DESCRIPTION + " ASC";
private static int[] TO = {R.id.itemrowid, R.id.itemdescription, R.id.itemun };
private EventsData events;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    events = new EventsData(this);
    try {
        Cursor cursor = getEvents();
        showEvents(cursor);
     } finally {
        events.close();
     }

**public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // What statement to put here to get the value of _ID,DESCRIPTION, UN
    // selected**?
}

private Cursor getEvents() {
    // Perform a managed query. The Activity will handle closing
    // and re-querying the cursor when needed.
    SQLiteDatabase db = events.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null,
            null, ORDER_BY);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}

private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
    // Set up data binding
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.item, cursor, FROM, TO);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603429/how-to-get-value-from-database-onlistitemclick/5603584#5603584

Answer (score 8):

First, you need to obtain item at clicked position:

```
Cursor cursor = getListAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Then you can get data from this cursor (I don't know what types do you use, so just for example it will be `int` and `String`):

```
int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESCRIPTION));
```

See [documentation](http://d.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) for Cursor's available methods.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to sergey answer you can also directly see what View was clicked and use `findViewById()` to find the components, therefore, the values you want.

This is just an alternative being the method Sergey much less 'patchy'