# Using a SimpleCursorAdapter + Sqlite doesn't seem to work on a ListActivity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've just started out building a very simple score screen for my app but nothing seems to be happening and I can't figure out why.

The ListActivity:

```
public class HighScoresActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.high_scores);

        ScoresDatabase db = new ScoresDatabase(this);
        Cursor data = db.getHighScores();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data, new String[] { "level" }, new int[] { R.id.level_text });
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        data.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

high_scores.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/level_text"/>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There are no error messages whatsoever, simply nothing happens.
Its not that the cursor is blank either, when I test the adapter.getCount() method, it returns ~30, which is exactly as expected.

I think all the function names are pretty much intuitive but if you need any clarification, just ask.

Any help is greatly apprechiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was 2 problems with my first code.

The first is as MisterSquonk pointed out, prematurely close the cursor and the database.

The second was in correctly binding the data to the views.

Here is the code of my now working solution

HighScoresActivity:

```
public class HighScoresActivity extends ListActivity {

    private Cursor data;
    private ScoresDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.high_scores);

        db = new ScoresDatabase(this);
        data = db.getHighScores();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.high_scores_entry, data, 
                new String[] { "level", "moves" }, 
                new int[] { R.id.level_entry, 
                R.id.moves_entry });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        data.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

high_scores.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

high_scores_entry.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/level_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/moves_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The way I had the data originally bound made no sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.close(); // DON'T DO THIS
```

From the docs for Cursor.close()...

> Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making it completely invalid. Unlike deactivate() a call to requery() will not make the Cursor valid again.

The `Adapter` for a `ListView` has to have a 'live' `Cursor` otherwise it won't function. Also, closing the database isn't always a good thing and can have adverse effects in certain cases (in my experience) - I'm not sure if that would also be causing a problem though.

**EDIT:** In light of Dave Newton's comment and having checked some of my own code, the problem will be with calling `close()` on both the `Cursor` and also the database. In short, remove the following lines...

```
data.close();
db.close();
```

Comment: It does cause a problem, hence the comments in my answer, although I said db, not data, cuz I pasted wrong. Although this issue would have been masked by the other issue, I think.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, you're right. I've since checked on some of my own code I wrote about 6 months ago which uses SimpleCursorAdapter with a ListView. Turns out I'd even left a comment in there warning me not to call `close()` on the database (which I'd obviously originally tried).

Comment: This didn't fix it, but it was part of the solution. To get it working, I had to change the line to -   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.high_scores_entry, data, new String[] { "level", "moves" }, new int[] { R.id.level_entry, R.id.moves_entry });. This way the data correctly binds to the views, I had misunderstood the documentation on doing it before

Answer (score 0):

You need to call...

```
db.open();
```

at the beginning of onCreate().

This will open your database and allow for data to be retrieved.

Comment: Hmm, I think OP said an `adapter.getCount()` worked, at least implying that that was wrapped up in the `ScoresDatabase` class--but I'm guessing on that.

Comment: Like Dave said, the database side of things appears to be working since the adapter is saying that it should have some elements in it (and I did some testing on the cursor itself to verify this). Also, there is no open() method on the ScoresDatabase which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter in the `SimpleCursorAdapter` ctor should be the ID of the list layout's field, `android.R.id.text1`.

The `R.id.level_text` is the ID of the text field you're using as a header; its text should be set from a string resource, either in the layout file, or dynamically in the `onCreate` method if you're reusing that layout.

Comment: I changed it to ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data, new String[] { "level" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });. But still the same result - nothing :/

Comment: @MarkD <strike>It's your LinearLayout; checking to see which fill/wrap it is.</strike> Hmm, it's still working for me. Hang on.

Comment: @MarkD You sure there's a column called "level"? What's getHighScores() look like? I can't make this not work.

Comment: @MarkD It's that db.close(); I don't think you want to call it there. Crap, no way to get two accepted answers ;)

Comment: @MarkD **Finally** found someone else saying the same thing; I was unable to find corroborating documentation. [See this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156836/get-selected-item-from-listview-bound-with-simplecursoradapter) I *assumed* it was like a JDBC `ResultSet`, and still do, but I have yet to see any *official* docs say so.