# Passing info through an Activity switch

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass information through an Activity switch.
I currently have an Activity where I can add a client to the database, and I have an Activity to view all clients in a ListView.

What I want is that when the user clicks on a client in the ListView for it to go back to the addclient Activity, with all the fields filled in from the database.

here is the Activity where the user views the clients

```
public class ViewClientActivity extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewclient_activity);

    DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();
    final Cursor ClientCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM clients", null);
    ListView allClients = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.allClients);
    final ClientCursorAdapter clientAdapter = new ClientCursorAdapter(this, ClientCursor);

    allClients.setAdapter(clientAdapter);

    allClients.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Intent AddClientActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddClientActivity.class);
            startActivity(AddClientActivity);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you need any additional information

Comment: There you have an answer. Please let me know if you'd rather want some more explanations on it

Comment: thank you sir ill give that a shot

Comment: i do have one more question... Whats the best way to know what listitem was clicked so i can transfer maybe a name or address and SELECT that from the database

Comment: You have to use the ViewHolder pattern and on the constructor of the viewHolder set the onClick listener. If you use a recyclerview you can get the adapter position with ```getAdapterPosition``` and if you use a listview you can add a random object into the ```setTag``` of a view. This is a method every view has

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156836/get-selected-item-from-listview-bound-with-simplecursoradapter#6156962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing to pass the information i needed

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            IMAGES = imagesPath[0] + "|" + imagesPath[1] + "|" + imagesPath[2] + "|" +
                        imagesPath[3] + "|" + imagesPath[4] + "|" + imagesPath[5];

            Intent intent = new Intent(AddClientActivity.this, ImageViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("IMAGES", IMAGES);
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the client class information implements `Parcelable` class. This way you will be able to add that information into the `Intent` you use to open the second Activity. From the second activity, you can get this information from the bundle obtained by calling  `getIntent()`

To add the `Parcelable` data into de intent use `intent.putExtra()` and to get it from it use `intent.getParcelableExtra()`

Comment: If all the fields are builtins, then its as simple as `intent.getStringExtra(key, default)` for strings :) Check this link for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: Also, I am just explaining the full object case scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

> when he clicks on a client in the listview for it to go back to the addclient activity but with all the fields filled in from the database

When you "go back", you are doing a `SELECT *`, so everything will be selected and updated correctly, assuming it was updated in the database.

Your task exists within the `AddClientActivity` to create a `new DBHandler` and update your data accordingly.

If you need to pass anything, it would be the ID of the row that was clicked, which you can use `setTag` within the `ClientCursorAdapter` class's `getView` method on the inflated view to put. Then, `(Long) view.getTag()` to receive in the click.

Also, please use `getReadableDatabase()` for CursorAdapter